# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client namespace-- Sharepoint namespace not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I installed [SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b4579045-b183-4ed4-bf61-dc2f0deabe47) with the intent of creating a basic console app to retrieve the site name as demonstrated in [Using the SharePoint Foundation 2010 Managed Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx#SP2010ClientOM_Using_CAML_Query_List) article on MSDN.

In the section detailing how a developer creates a console application, the article creates the following code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

class DisplayWebTitle
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://intranet.contoso.com");
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(site);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", site.Title);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the namespace: Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client (squiggly underline underneath sharepoint) is not recognized.  As a result, ClientContext and Web are not recognized.  What do I do to get this to namespace to resolve?

Comment: Also, make sure you take a look at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ when you have SharePoint questions.  You are much more likely to get an answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go to properties for the project and modify "Target Framework" to target ".NET Framework 4" instead of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that assembly has been added to your References.  You should be able to add it from your 12/14 hive.

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539757.aspx) it can be found here:

%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI

Comment: what's a 12/14 hive?  I have a regular developer workstation that does not have sharepoint installed. Is there some sdk that needs to be installed?

Comment: Did you install the Client Object Model on your workstation?  If so it should be in the path above

Comment: nope, I don't have an ISAPI directory.  I installed the 2010 redistributable, but I don't have this directory.  I do have a 14\BIN, but not what you are suggesting

Comment: Poke around in your 14 folder (start in the BIN dir) and see if you can find `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`.  If you have it on your machine I'm pretty sure it would be there.  Once you find it add it to the References in your project.